# Git rebase changes onto master from an ancestor

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

So i've got the following situation where we branched for our release and continued enhancements are being added to master.

```
A---B---C---Q---W---E---R---T  master
     \         /
      D---E---F Release 1
               \
                G---H---I Release Fixes
```

Changes up to `F` of 'Release 1' are merged back into 'master'. Is there a way to rebase/replay the 'Release Fixes' change back onto 'master'?

---

**Edit**

To provide more information, I have done a cherry-pick of a series of commits and some of the inspected files don't seem to be at the right version. If a merge is suggested, is it possible to do a merge between two commits?

Comment: does the merge to master fail? you may have to solve some conflicts, but it should work.

Comment: I second the previous comment, why don't you just _merge_?

Comment: the reason I ask is that i've done a cherry-pick of a large number of commits and some files are not up to date w/ the latest commit. can i do a `git merge <hash>..<hash>` so that the changes that git merged are reduced to a sub-set of the branch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `rebase` command would be:

```
git rebase --onto master F I      #<realse1>..<release-fixes>
```

Not that this will remove commits G, H, and I from F and create G', H', and I' on T.  If you want to leave G, H, and I in-place then you'd do:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick G H I    # <release1>..<release-fixes>
```

[edit] or, as +kirelagin points out, just do a merge to leave them in place.

Comment: If you want to leave them in-place, then you normally do _merge_.